# Efficient algorithm for finding intervals in a DAG

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Apologies if I don’t use the right terminology, I’m an outsider to the field. Also I'm not sure whether to post this here or in programmers.stackexchange as my aim is primarily to find an efficient *algorithm* to solve the following problem. Please tell me off if I'm in the wrong place.

**Problem**:

I have a (transitive) DAG $G=(V,E)$ with $N=|V|$ vertices.

For any pair of vertices $u,v\in V$ such that $(u,v)\in E$ define the “interval” between $u$ and $v$ as the set $$I(u,v) = \{w \in G: (u,w)\in E \text{ and }(w,v)\in E\}.$$

I want to find an efficient algorithm that counts the number $N_k$ of intervals of cardinality $k$ for a given DAG $G$.

**Notes:**

The brute force approach - representing G with an adjacency matrix and scanning through the entries - takes $O(N^3)$. My graphs are typically sparse, $|E|<0.25N^2$. Making little adjustments to the brute force approach I’ve been able to make things a little quicker but I haven’t been able to get my speed below $O(N^3)$. Perhaps there is an obvious reason that this task can’t be performed faster than $O(N^3)$? Any comments welcome.

Comment: The question of efficiency will depend crucially on how dense your graph is. If the average number of outgoing neighbors of a node is small you should try each one in turn for every node.  This will be $O(nb^2)$  where $b$ is the average outdegree.  However if the average outdegree is really linear in the number of nodes it's not a great method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Strassen-Algorithm can square the adjacency matrix in $O(|V|^{\log_2 7})$.